# How to get jasmine to read single file Vue components?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, vue.js

So I have jasmine and vue installed through npm but when I import the component itself, which is a .vue file, it can't read the template, which is between `<template></template>` tags. I am also using webpack and not sure if I need to do something with that.

Here's what a vue component file looks like

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'test',
    data: {},
    computed: {}
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.vue` files need to be compiled, if you are using `webpack` then you need to use [vue-loader](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) to transform your templates into `plain javascript`, internally `vue-loader` will take all the code between the template tags and convert them to [render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). You should start by taking a look at the docs for [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and [webpack template](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) to start building your Vue apps.

If you are only getting started with Vue.js, I would suggest you to go for [standalone version](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Standalone) of Vue.js, which is a simple javascript file that you can include using script tags and then start playing around with components and templates.

Once you get used to the idea of creating various components and defining templates, you can start with [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and the [webpack template](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) to build your complex apps.